# “Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or...”

Tags: java, hibernate

I got following problem in my hibernate program.

I got user class

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @ManyToMany
    private int id;
```

and game class

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "id")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int winnerID;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "id")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int loserID;
```

So i want my game class winnerID and loserID store information about loser and winner of each game. But it return error "Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements:"

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you explain, in your own words, what a _many-to-many_ relationship is, and what kind of data value you need to describe the "many" related records?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I want my user to have many games, and games can have same user winning multiple games. Isnt the relation proper?

Comment: How can you express _many_ games with a single `int`?